# Encoding the x64 VEX prefix

Tags: 64-bit, machine-code

I'm using this guide to the VEX prefix: http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix

I'm lost on how to encode actual VEX instructions though.  The ADDPD instruction (Intel x64 page 459) Opcode looks like this: VEX.NDS.128.66.0F.WIG 58 /r

Ummm what??  The VEX guide doesn't say anything about 'NDS' or 'WIG'.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing section 3.1.1.2 "Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table (Instructions with VEX prefix)" (page 64 in the manual I have on my PC, probably slightly different in other versions)

For this instance, the important parts are:

- `VEX` (obviously) means there is a VEX prefix.
- `NDS`, the VEX.vvvv field specifies a register (it doesn't always, sometimes it is unused and must be set to all ones) and that it is a read-only first source operand.
- `128` fairly obvious, it's the 128bit wide version
- `55`, it doesn't say that, it says `66` or at least it should. Other choices are F2, F3, and "nothing". Indicates what the values of the VEX.pp field should be, corresponds to mandatory prefix in the old encoding.
- `0F`, opcode map specifier, corresponds to 0F prefix in the old encoding (there are also 0F3A and 0F38)
- `WIG` (other options are `W1` and `W0`), means the VEX.W field is ignored (`W0` and `W1` mean the `W` bit must be respectively 0 or 1)

Comment: Thanks Harold!  You are right, it's 66.  However I can't seem to find that section in my intel manual.  Chapter 13 says it's AVX but it doesn't say anything about the VEX prefix.  What do 'NDS' and 'WIG' stand for?

Comment: "W"-IGnored, you can read NDS as NonDestructive Source, but the other options are NDD (vvvv encodes a destination .. yea, not so much NonDestructive) (used in BMI) and DDS (source and destination, seems to be FMA-only)

Comment: So what would be the complete instruction for say adding registers xmm1 and xmm2 -> xmm3?  Sorry for being a pain I just don't want to mess it up and then have wrong instructions everywhere...

Comment: `vaddpd xmm3, xmm1, xmm2` (`C5 E9 58 D9`) or you can swap the sources

Comment: How about when one of the sources is from memory?  I assume it switches to three-byte VEX (what is XOP?).

Comment: You don't need a 3 byte VEX prefix to encode a memory operand (for example, `vaddpd xmm3, xmm1, [rax]` is `C5 F1 58 18`). You need it when `X`, `B` or `W` are not zero, or when `map_select` is not 00001 (`0F`). XOP is always a 3 byte prefix, it is used for AMD-specific instructions

Comment: The map select bit is confusing.  If it's 0x0F by default, why does the guide say it's 00001 by default?  0x0F is 01111.  The guide doesn't say it's inverted or anything...

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant that map_select = 00001 corresponds to "just plain 0F" (as opposed to 0F3A or 0F38) in the old encoding. XOP uses map_select of 8 and up by the way, but that doesn't correspond to anything because those instructions have no legacy encoding.

Comment: Ok you might have to pound this one into my thick skull.  Where does it list where 0x0F = b00001?  I see other instructions that list 0x0F3A, what is the map select there?  0x0F3A is two bytes and map select is only 5 bits

Comment: 0F38 -> 00010, 0F3A -> 00011, any other map_selects (there are clearly plenty more possibilities) are reserved. There's a table of this in [AMD's manual](http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24594.pdf)

Comment: Thanks!  Not sure what'd I'd do without you Harold!